# Andengine: Change size of a sprite's repeating texture on the fly

Tags: opengl-es, andengine

I am painting a rope. It is a Sprite built using a 16x16 texture that is repeated (using TextureOptions.REPEATING_BILINEAR, to 16 x ropeLength).
The problem is that I need to change the rope length "on the fly" (I am already doing it in onManagedUpdate), but I would like to change also the texture length, and so avoid de "ellastic" effect that happens when changing the sprite length without changing the texture length (the repeating textures are stretched or contracted to match the new sprite size).

I have confirmed that using "this.getTextureRegion().setTextureSize()" has no effect after the Sprite has been created.

Can anybody help me or give some ideas.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to modify the u/v coordinates of the vertices instead. Unfortunately I don't know how to do that in Andengine. Perhaps it's somewhere "near" the function you use to extend the rope (i.e. modify x/y/z coordinates of vertices). Hope this helps.

Comment: Sorry. I can not "translate" this info into AndEngine concepts that I handle (In fact, I don't know anything about u/v coordinates). Anybody can give me some explanations about this response?

Comment: Finally, I have understood what you said. For anybody who is interested, the function I had to call to achieve this in AndEngine is: 'this.getVertexBufferObject().onUpdateTextureCoordinates(this)' (called after modifying the texture size). Thank you very much for your help!!!.